# Objective C iOS - Transition from main UiView to another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a small app that scans barcode. at the end of the my if condition "when it finds the data and updates the label on the screen, I want to automatically move to a blank view that I have created.

My function when it finds the metadata from firstView.m is below

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
     CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
     AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
     NSString *detectionString = nil;
     NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                          AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                          AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

     for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
       for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
          if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
          {
            barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
            highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
            detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
            break;
        }
    }

        if (detectionString != nil)
        {
           _label.text = detectionString;
            break;

        }
        else
          _label.text = @"Barcode not found";
   }

    _highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect;
}
```

My other view that I want to transition to is a UIViewController that has a navigation controller before it. Please let know what I need to do and if I should keep the Navigation controller or take it off.

My story board below. **The barcode scanner is in First View Controller and I want to transition to the UIView that has a Navigation Controller under the name "Sameer"**
[image]

Comment: where is the blankview and how u created it?

Comment: I updated my question :) @Mr.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by @Ares is correct .However you have not provided enough information whether you want to move to a UINavigationController or move to a UIViewController.

I assume your current UIViewController don't have any UINavigationController,in that case ,if you want to present the blanvView controller without navigation controller, you can present it modally using storyboardID.

Else if you want to present blanview controller with navigation, then you need to present the navigation controller which already has blank view controller.

Edit:

Give your view controller a storyboardID, and do:

```
 detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
 MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
 break;
```

Comment: I understand that and thats why I posted my storyboard and code. I want to present the UIViewController that contains a UITable in it. I did what Ares suggested, but I was directed to a blank black screen. Instead I want to show the UIView Controller that has the table. I hope I became clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your blank view right after, then push it to the navigation controller if you are using one or simply present the view controller. So

```
    detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];

   UIViewController *blankView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:blackView animated:YES];
break;
```

Comment: Thank you, but nothing really happened when I added the line you provided. I updated my question and put a picture of the storyboard.